# Convergence of the sum of all odd digit numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

[image]

This problem came in my mocks. I tried writing the sum down and sandwiching it but I could not find appropriate "sandwiches" to this. Please help me with this. I nearly spent an hour on it and could not find a solution.

Comment: It looks like it's an accident, but please try not to repost questions. If you want to edit your previous question, you can: just press [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4784714/edit) below the post's tags.

Comment: Actually , not the numbers itself are summed up , but their reciprocals.